# How to make an anchor element (<a>) the size of a list item (<li>)

Tags: html, css

I want to make `<a>` the size of `<li>`, so a click can be received anywhere inside the `li`.

`span` is there to be adjusted to act as a title in the block (but maybe that's another question?)

Here's my CSS

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
}

.header-cont {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.header {
    background-color: #f9c868;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    color: black;       
}

.content {
    /*background: #F0F0F0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 600px;
    text-align: center;*/
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap
}

.section {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.content li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.content li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width: calc(50% - 4px);
    margin-right: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}

.content li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

li a {

    display: block;
  }

@media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
 .content li {
    width: calc(25% - 6px);
  }

 .content li:nth-of-type(2n) {
    margin-right: 8px;
  }

 .content li:nth-of-type(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.content li:hover {
  transform: rotate(1deg);
}
```

And here is my HTML

```
<template name="home">
    <section class="section">
        <div class="content">

            <li>
                <a href="www.google.com"></a>
                <span>

                </span>
                <p>This is a list 1</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>
                <span>

                </span>
                <p>This is a list 2</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>
                <span>

                </span>
                <p>This is a list 2</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>
                <span>

                </span>
                <p>This is a list 2</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>
                <span>

                </span>
                <p>This is a list 2</p>`
            </li>

        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  The `li` tag also has `span` and `p` tags inside of it.  What is supposed to happen to them?

Comment: You can Use Width:inherit; for <a>

Comment: `Span` is just supposed to hold some text. The `a` should cover all of them since everything is inside `li`

Comment: So just close the `a` after each `p` element and you have everything, both the `span` and the `p` wrapped inside. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: `li` is the parent and visually is bigger than any of it so clicking anywhere inside `li` should trigger the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If everything inside the `li` is supposed to be clickable, then wrap everything in the `li` in the `a`.

Here's an example:

```css
ul { padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }
    
li { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

a { display: block; }

span { display: block; background-color: aqua; }

p { margin: 0; background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="www.google.com">
            <span>span text span text span text</span>
            <p>paragraph content paragraph content paragraph content</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The key is to switch the default `display` value of inline elements to `display: block`, so they expand the full width of the `li` (block-level) container. The `p` is already a block element by default. But the `a` and `span` are `display: inline` and need to be adjusted.

Comment: Do we have to enclose this in a `ul` ?

Comment: If you're using list item tags (`li`), then yes. `li` elements are only valid inside `ul`, `ol` and `menu`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Comment: `li a {
    text-decoration:        none;
    display: block;
    padding: 1px;
    color: #000000;
  }`

This worked for me. padding set to 0px does nothing. Why ?

Comment: Not following you. `padding: 1px` vs. `padding: 0` makes a difference. Can you post a [fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Yeah it does. I'll try posting a fiddle demo.

Comment: Just change the padding of `li a` to `0` and you'll see that then `a` doesn't cover the whole `li`

https://jsfiddle.net/atnonkah/

Comment: The `a` contains a `p` element, which by default has top and bottom margins. When the `a` has `padding: 0`, the bottom margin of the `p` is cut-off, leaving a gap. When the `padding` is 1px, the bottom margin of the `p` can expand. https://jsfiddle.net/atnonkah/2/

Comment: Okay, so now I am more confused with CSS. How do I make the size of anchor text equal to the list item ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102800/discussion-between-basit-anwer-and-michael-b).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
li { position:relative; }
li a { position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; }
```

In this way the <a> covers the entire <li> element.
I would also suggest getting rid of the <span> elements. If you are trying to create space, just add some padding to the top of the <p> elements.